# Using recursion in a stored procedure in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, stored-procedures

I am going to find gcd of two integer numbers by using SQL stored procedure with recursion query. But I got stuck in a loop and I really don't know why, here is my code:

```
create or alter procedure sp_gcd 
    @s1 int, @s2 int
as
begin
    if (@s1 % @s2 = 0) 
        print @s2
    else if (@s2 % @s1 = 0) 
        print @s1
    else
        begin           
            while (@s2 % @s1 != 0)
                begin
                     declare @temp int = @s2 % @s1 
                     exec sp_gcd @temp, @s1
                end
            print @s1
        end     
 end
 exec sp_gcd 15,21
```

And this is the result:

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
...
```

I just start working with SQL so I will very much appreciate if anyone could help, thanks a lot.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: Side note (if this is for **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: It is ssms and my teacher told me to add ```sp_``` prefix

Answer (score 1):

stack calls:

```
sp_gcd 15 21
sp_gcd 6 15
sp_gcd 3 6
print 3
sp_gcd 3 6
print 3
sp_gcd 3 6
print 3
```

The reason for this to happen is that the while loop, inside the procedure call sp_gcd 6 15, never reaches the false condition; that is, the condition `15 % 6!=0` is always true.